# Grunt: cssmin not working

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am trying to minify CSS using Grunt cssmin plugin. Below is my code:

```
// Minify CSS
cssmin: {
    build: {
        options: {
            banner: '/* Minified CSS */'
        },

        files: {
            'htt/css/style.min.css' : ['wp/css/**/*.css']
        }   
    }
},
```

when i run "grunt cssmin" it gives error of "Unexpected identifier".

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error in your css, try pasting them here and see if they pass http://www.css-validator.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: There are two files, one is bootstrap.css and other is my own style.css. Kindly check the link of my own style.css [link](http://pastebin.com/1Z2avFng)

Comment: Seems fine, can you post your full Gruntfile.js and the full error that gets printed, i'm starting to think you have a stray comma somewhere in your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where missing a comma after the js object in the watch task, for future you can edit your answer to provide more information instead of posting it as an answer :)

```
        // Watch Tasks
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['wp/js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify:dev']
            }, <------- Missing comma

            css: {
                files: ['wp/css/*.css'],
                tasks: ['']
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

@mike

`module.exports = function (grunt) {

```
// Configure Tasks
grunt.initConfig ({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON ('package.json'),

    // Uglify JS
    uglify: {
        build: {
            src: 'wp/js/*.js',
            dest: 'htt/js/script.min.js'
        },

        dev: {
            options: {
                beautify: true,
                mangel: false,
                compress: false,
                preserveComments: 'all'
            },
            src: 'wp/js/*.js',
            dest: 'htt/js/script.min.js'
        }
    },

    // Concatenating files
    concat: {
        build: {
            src: ['wp/css/*.css'],
            dest: 'htt/css/style.css'
        }
    },

    // Minify CSS
    cssmin: {
        build: {
            //options: {
            //  banner: '/* Minified CSS */'
            //},

            files: {
                'htt/css/style.min.css' : ['wp/css/**/*.css']
            }   
        }
    },

    // Watch Tasks
    watch: {
        js: {
            files: ['wp/js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['uglify:dev']
        }

        css: {
            files: ['wp/css/*.css'],
            tasks: ['']
        }
    }
});

// Load the Plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

// Register Tasks
grunt.registerTask ('default', ['uglify:dev']);
grunt.registerTask ('build', ['uglify:build', 'cssmin']);
```

};`

Above is the whole gruntfile.js file